# Beautiful Soup not returning results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a page with BS in python.

Here is my code:

```
years = range(2010,2021)

urls = []

for year in years:
    yr = str(year)
    url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nba/contracts/breakdown/'+yr+'/'
    webpage = requests.get(url)
    content = webpage.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub("<!--|-->","", content.decode('utf-8')),'lxml')
    a = soup.find('table',{'class':'datatable'})
    urls.append(a)
```

I am getting no results. I have double and triple checked the class of the table in the page source.  I believe (though I think this is where the error is) - that I have properly coded the soup variable to account for the commented section of the page source.

Comment: Have you checked the result you get from the request? What's with the `re.sub("<!--|-->","", content.decode('utf-8'))` ?

Answer (score 1):

`str(range(2010,2021))` will produce a string `'range(2010, 2021)'`. And then you iterate over each char of that string. So first value of year is `r` and so on.

In addition the site requires premium subscription and you need to log in to see data

`

Comment: Thanks, @buran - that was a silly mistake.  I've fixed the str issue in the OP.  However, I am still getting no results.  I actually do have a premium subsciption, do you know how I would enter credentials when attempting to parse?

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: You will need to make a request to the login page. Depending on how their site is built depend on whether you can just make a POST request to an endpoint and log in or if you need to scrape the login form for hidden fields, CSRF tokens as well as sending over the correct cookies. The best general advice is to go look at their page, view the source and follow the requests through a normal browser with a developer toolbar seeing what is sent and then recreate that in code.